# Magento2: Editing attribute 'country_of_manufacture' is impossible

Tags: magento2, attributes

[image]

I want to edit the attribute `country_of_manufacture` by adding german translation(for german store view) for each value in the options section, but
I can't do so.

Is there a way how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Can you tell me which type of attribute you have created?

Comment: or just post that attribute creation code here.

Comment: this attribute was already there after magento2 installation

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. I spent hours for this. As I wanted `"Country of Manufacturer"` to be displayed on Category Filter.

**As it's Magento Default System Attribute you can't do anything, even from the database as well.**

I tried with Database also, still, it didn't work.

**Solution:**

Make you Custom Attribute with your named say example `"Manufacturer"` & input all the values as you have input
`"Country of Manufacturer"` Attribute (it's long but no choice).

Then it will work out. So remove `"Country of Manufacturer"` from Attribute Set & Set your once.

That way will work. I solved an issue by this way. No better option for Now. I think.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that from the start, but I thought maybe there is a way to customize that attribute...looks like there is no way