# Modify System Attribute - Add an option to msrp_display_actual_price_type attribute

Tags: magento2.2.4

I want to add a "call for price" or "price on application" functionality to a site which basically hides the price and add to cart buttons for a product.

I have created another attribute for now however feel it would be neater to use the `msrp_display_actual_price_type` attribute and add a "Price on Application" option as this is the logical place for it to go.

This is however a system attribute and from within admin there seems to be no way to add options to this attribute.

There seems to be a similar question here [Magento2: Editing attribute 'country_of_manufacture' is impossible](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144589/magento2-editing-attribute-country-of-manufacture-is-impossible) however this states it's not possible but surely there is a way or atleast should be at your own risk adding a value shouldn't do much harm.

So far im thinking to just override `magento/module-msrp/Model/Product/Attribute/Source/Type.php` within a custom module. Adjusting like so:

```
<type name="Magento\Msrp\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Type">
    <plugin name="callforprice_updatepoa" type="Harrigo\CallForPrice\Plugin\Updatedap"/>
</type>
<!--<preference for="Magento\Msrp\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Type" type="Harrigo\CallForPrice\Model\Updatedap" />-->
```

> **di.xml**

I tried with preference however this did not seem to do anything however with **plugins** i could modify and add the value which shows and saves fine everything seems to work however i could not access the protected variable `$this->_options` and so have to skip the if statement that checks is it is set. Can i get away access with this / access this variable at all?

```
    if (!$this->_options) {
        $this->_options = [
            ['label' => __('On Gesture'), 'value' => self::TYPE_ON_GESTURE],
            ['label' => __('In Cart'), 'value' => self::TYPE_IN_CART],
            ['label' => __('Before Order Confirmation'), 'value' => self::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM],
        ];
    }
    return $this->_options;
```

> **Original Function**

```
<?php
namespace Harrigo\CallForPrice\Plugin;

class Updatedap
{
/**
 * Display Product Price on gesture
 */
const TYPE_ON_GESTURE = 1;

/**
 * Display Product Price in cart
 */
const TYPE_IN_CART = 2;

/**
 * Display Product Price before order confirmation
 */
const TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM = 3;

/**
 * Price on Application
 */
const TYPE_PRICE_ON_APPLICATION = 4;

function afterGetAllOptions($subject)
{
    $_options = [
        ['label' => __('On Gesture'), 'value' => self::TYPE_ON_GESTURE],
        ['label' => __('In Cart'), 'value' => self::TYPE_IN_CART],
        ['label' => __('Before Order Confirmation'), 'value' => self::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM],
        ['label' => __('Price on Application'), 'value' => self::TYPE_PRICE_ON_APPLICATION],
    ];
    return $_options;
}
}
```

> **Plugin**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is correct to do so someone please comment on this if anything seems a miss.

I have used a plugin as using a preference for the class didn't seem to work.

### Add below to module's **di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Msrp\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Type">
    <plugin name="callforprice_updatepoa" type="Harrigo\CallForPrice\Plugin\Updatedap"/>
</type>
```

> **di.xml**

## Create plugin code:

```
<?php
namespace Harrigo\CallForPrice\Plugin;

class Updatedap extends \Magento\Msrp\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Type
{
    /**
     * Price on Application
     */
    const TYPE_PRICE_ON_APPLICATION = 4;

    function afterGetAllOptions(\Magento\Msrp\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Type $subject)
    {
        if (!$this->_options) {
            $this->_options = [
                ['label' => __('On Gesture'), 'value' => self::TYPE_ON_GESTURE],
                ['label' => __('In Cart'), 'value' => self::TYPE_IN_CART],
                ['label' => __('Before Order Confirmation'), 'value' => self::TYPE_BEFORE_ORDER_CONFIRM],
                ['label' => __('Price on Application'), 'value' => self::TYPE_PRICE_ON_APPLICATION],
            ];
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }
}
```

> **Plugin/Updatedap.php**

I extended the method within the plugin code so that i could access the protected variables. Not sure if i should do this however seemed to overcome my issue.